# Do the bad rewards from the quest Cacklespit's Brew have any hidden value?

Tags: torchlight-2

Cacklespit provides three very bad rewards... is there any way they are not as bad as they seem? Do they level up to become awesome? If you survive 13 minutes of the brew, do you get a prize? Should I even avoid turning in the quest? Cacklespit seems a right unpleasant bloke.

[image]

Comment: 243,602 health over 13.33 minutes (800 seconds) means ~305 "dps", btw. (Your mileage may vary; apparently the actual health loss scales with you.)

Comment: the only reason to go into cracklespit's brew level is to find to final peace of the robot.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't appear to do anything special. I gave it to my pet and it fled around for 12.5 minutes. I intend to take it myself in another playthrough just to see if I can survive it. If you have over 90hp/sec regen you should be able to survive just sitting there.

There is a second cacklespit quest that you can get if you complete the first one. There you kill him.

Comment: Don't drink it. I drank it and, well, you just see your health bar drop quickly for as long as you care to keep yourself sustained. Not worth it.